# There are 9 people in a lift of 12 storey house.they have to leave the lift in groups of 2,3 and 4 at different storeys..no.of ways?

Tags: combinatorics

( Lift does not stop at second storey)..No.of ways of selecting 2,3and4 people out of 9 people is (9C2*7C3*4C4)...no.of ways of selecting 3 storeys out of 11 storeys is 11C3...total no of ways by which people can leave the lift should be (9C2*7C3*4C4)*11C3*3!...but my answer is wrong...I don't know where I am making mistake?

Comment: Your departure group size options, according to the title, are - if a group of five departs, then  $\{5,2,2\}$, otherwise $\{3,3,3\}$ or $\{3,2,2,2\}$. These are best treated as three separate calculations.

Comment: Sorry I just made a mistake it is 4 not 5...and they have to depart only in a group of 2,3 and 4

Comment: OK, same logic, except the group-of-four option looks like $\{4,3,2\}$

Answer (score 2):

So, three group departure patterns available:

- case $1$: $\{4,3,2\}$

  - floor choice for the various groups is $10\cdot 9\cdot 8$, assuming that they don't get off at the first or second storeys, since didn't they just get on at the first? - then choosing who is in the groups, $\binom {9}{4,3,2} = \frac {9!}{4!\,3!\,2!}$
- case $2$: $\{3,3,3\}$

  - choose $3$ floors from the $10$ available, $\binom {10}{3}$, then assign the people into those groups, $\binom {9}{3,3,3}   = \frac {9!}{3!\,3!\,3!}$
- case $3$: $\{3,2,2,2\}$

  - choose a floor for the group of $3$ then choose $3$ floors for the groups of $2$, $10\cdot \binom 93$, and choose the people by  $\binom {9}{3,2,2,2}   = \frac {9!}{3!\,2!\,2!\,2!}$

Overall:
$$\frac{10!}{7!} \frac {9!}{4!\,3!\,2!} + \frac{10!}{7!\,3!} \frac {9!}{3!\,3!\,3!} + \frac{10!}{6!\,3!} \frac {9!}{3!\,2!\,2!\,2!}
$$

---

Alternatively, the question - instead of restricting the possible group sizes as I read it  - could be asking for the scenarios where the departures are exactly one group of $4$, one group of $3$ and one group of $2$, in which case the answer is only as in case $1$, $\frac{10!}{7!} \frac {9!}{4!\,3!\,2!}$, or if there are $11$ floor departure choices,  $\frac{11!}{8!} \frac {9!}{4!\,3!\,2!}$  - which matches your answer, once you multiplied in the $3!$ to shift from ${}_{11}C_3{}$ to ${}_{11}P_3{}$.

So either the number of available exit floors is $10$ or the question did mean that you should consider all possible scenarios that include only groups of $2,3,4$ leaving per floor (or both). Do you have the book answer, in numeric, factorial or combinatorial form?

Comment: Don't you think that all possibilities you found in second case is a subset of first case..

Comment: For example we have 3 people that depart for 9th floor...considering your  second case we have same three people that depart for 9th floor...don't you think these 2 cases are same?

Comment: They're not the same scenario, because the other people get off in a different pattern. Each person only has $10$ choices, but without any other constraints that would give $10^9$ scenarios, not $90$.

Comment: @Akulsharma updated answer with a little more discussion and requesting the book answer to assess where the difference is.

Comment: Sorry unfortunately answer is 10P3

Comment: This would mean that the people are indistinguishable, which is a poorly-written question. Generally people are taken to be distinct.

Comment: How people can be indistinguishable?

Comment: Exactly, they can't. That's why I say it was a badly-written question. So your answer was better (even ignoring the trap on how many exit floors available)

Comment: So should I consider my answer correct?and thanks you did lot for this question

Comment: Your answer was good for 11 exit floor options and exact groups of 4, 3 and 2 exiting.